# How to convert file to buffer in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am writing a sails.js app. I am writing an API to accept a file and encrypt it.

```
var file = req.body('myFile');
var fileBuffer = convertToBuffer(file);
```

How do I convert a file to buffer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That looks like you've got a string which represents the body of your file.

You just have to make a [new buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) with it.

```
var fileBuffer = Buffer.from(file)
```

If your encoding is NOT `utf8` you can specify an alternate encoding as a second optional argument.

```
var fileBuffer = Buffer.from(file, 'base64')
```

If the file is actually on disk, this is even easier, since, by default, the `fs.readFile` operation returns a buffer.

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, buffer){})
```

If you're in a *real* old version of node `Buffer.from` doesn't exist and you have to use a very memory-unsafe `new` constructor. Please consider upgrading your node instance to support `Buffer.from`

Comment: If you're just now coming to this comment, please know that `new Buffer` has been deprecated in replace of `Buffer.from(...)`. You can read more about this here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_object_offsetorencoding_length

Comment: @ChasenBettinger thanks for the heads up -- updated to show the proper usage of Buffer

Comment: Its hard to find answers for File Object, tsk tsk

Comment: If anyone here is a frontend developer, confused with backend operations, and was looking for File Object -> Buffer, while uploading image files on server, know that on server files should be processed with library like Busboy and will become FileStreams, not File Objects. So you need to convert FileStream to Buffer - that's probably what you're looking for. I answered on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77429654/10489004