# How to turn a File object into a buffer for Sharp to understand?

Tags: javascript, node.js, form-data, sharp

I have an object of type `File` which is being handled by a Node.js backend.

```js
export default function handler(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse<Object>) {
  console.log("METHOD: ", req.method)
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.parse(req, (error: any, fields: any, files: any) => {
      console.log(fields)
      console.log(files.image)
      await Sharp(Buffer.from(files.image))
        .toFormat("webp")  
        .toFile("save.webp")
    })

    res.status(200).send({ message: "Success" })
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "POST only supported" })
  }
}
```

The `files.image` is of type `File` and when I try to pass it into `Buffer.from()` I would get an error

```
The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of File
```

I tried to pass in `await Sharp(Buffer.from(files.image, 'base64'))` but with the same error.  Is there some way I can turn `files.image` into Buffer Sharp can understand?

**UPDATE:** I found a way to accomplish my goal by using the following:

```js
if (req.method == "POST") {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.parse(req, (error: any, fields: any, files: any) => {

      // Pass in the temp file location where the incoming form stores the request  
      ConvertToWebP(files.image.path)  
    })

    res.status(200).send({ message: "Success" })
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "POST only supported" })
  }
}
```

After several hours of different approaches I found this through looking at the `File` object:

```json
{
  image: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 481,
    path: 'C:\\XXX\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_XXX',
    name: 'eagle.png',
    type: 'image/png',
    hash: null,
...
```

NOTE: I want to keep this question open because this workaround may work but I still want to understand why I can't pass in a Buffer object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Formidable [`File`](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#file) interface `filepath` property in order to read the uploaded file content into a Buffer.

```
...
import * as fs from 'fs';

...
const buf = await fs.promises.readFile(files.image.filepath);
await Sharp(buf);
...


...
```

Comment: I get an error `error - pages\api\image\index.ts (16:50) @ arrayBuffer
error - uncaughtException: TypeError: files.image.arrayBuffer is not a function`.

Comment: Edit my answer now that I understand that files.image is of type [formidable.File](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#file)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this question, trying to upload image files from client to server, and handle them with Sharp, here's how I did it:

On client, I'm sending the POST request with form data:

```js
  const formData = new FormData()

  for (const file of files) {
    formData.append("files", file, file.name)
  }

  const r = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
```

On server we need 1) to use middleware (e.g. Express or separate middleware file - I'm using the latter) to process form data of content type of multipart into FileStream (it's not gonna be File Objects), 2) process FileStream into data chunks, 3) merge array of data chunks with buffer (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729663/10489004) answer) and attach them to body. I used Busboy:

```js
  const busboy = require('busboy')

  const parseMultipartBody = (req, res, next) => {
    
    const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers })

    req.body.filesAsBuffer = []

    // every file here will be FileStream, not File Object
    bb.on('file', (name, file, info) => {
    
      const data = []
      let fileAsBuffer
    
      file.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data.push(chunk)
      }).on('close', () => {
        // merge data chunks with buffer and attach them to body
        fileAsBuffer = Buffer.concat(data)
        req.body.filesAsBuffer.push(fileAsBuffer)
      })
    })

    bb.on('close', () => {
      next()
    })
  
    req.pipe(bb)
  }
```

On the route we can use Sharp to do whatever operation we need:

```js
  const sharp = require('sharp')

  export const POST = async (req, res) => {

    const { body } = req
    const { filesAsBuffer } = body

    for (const fileAsBuffer of filesAsBuffer) {
      const metadata = await sharp(fileAsBuffer).metadata()
      console.log(1, metadata)
    }
   
    ...
  }
```